# Running Java program from commandline

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to run a java program from command line. I tried following the steps mentioned [here](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html). But when I try to run `javac Hello.java`, it's throwing error that such a program is not there. I tried giving `java Hello.java` and got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello.java
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Hello.java.  Program will exit.
```

What is the problem here. How can I do it?

EDIT: I have many classes in my code file, Hello.java. Will that cause any problem?

Comment: Are you using packages? do you see Hello.class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run the program you need to do:

```
java Hello
```

which is `java` followed by the class name *without extension*.

Comment: Still I am getting the "ClassNotFoundException" that I pasted above. My code is running fine in eclipse.

Comment: Or, depending on your environment, "java -classpath . Hello"

Comment: Can you edit your question to make clear that when running you program with `java Hello` it still doesnt work ? And can you put the stacktrace you get when running `java Hello` ?

Comment: I didn't have JDK. I thought eclipse will install everything. Now it works

Answer (score 6):

First you should compile the java code with

```
 javac Hello.java
```

Then run it

```
 java Hello
```

In both cases, make sure your classpath is set correctly...

Comment: Where can I find javac. It is not there in jre/../bin

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html - the JRE is to be able to "run", the JDK to be able to compile.

Answer (score 3):

First off, java requires at most one public class per file. No

```
public class this {
}

public class that {
}
```

You can have

```
class this {
   class that {
   }
}
```

if you need.

EDIT or in file this.java:

```
public class this {
}

class that {
}
```

javac won't be in the jre folder. Have you installed the jdk? it doesn't come by default on many computers. it's often in "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin\javac.exe" or a similiar path.

Comment: After installing jdk, I am able to run javac Hello.java and then java Hello. It runs correctly although I am having multiple (non-nested) classes.

Comment: That's correct - editing post. only one public class, which must have the same name as file.

Comment: Also, eclipse's javac is in a different place, and in IBM RAD (based on eclipse), it's not in the PATH environment variable. I don't know precisely where it would be. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the others answer, first, you have to run your application using `java Hello` and not `java Hello.java`

Second, you have to check that your `CLASSPATH` is correctly set. It seems that your variable is not set or does not integrate the current directory, i.e. `.`

So run :

```
javac -classpath . Hello.java
java -classpath Hello
```

or

```
set CLASSPATH=.
javac Hello.java
java Hello
```

Of course, defining the `CLASSPATH` as a user / system variable in your Windows system is a better solution!

Answer (score 1):

In case `Hello.java` is contained in a package, you will have to create an appropriate directory structure. I.e. in case `Hello.java` is contained in the package `com.stackoverflow`, you must create the folders `com/stackoverflow` and put `Hello.java` in this folder. From the root folder you must then launch

`java com.stackoverflow.Hello`